# Nodejs multer angular file upload error can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, angular, upload, multer

Usign Angular 5 Nodejs and Multer
I am trying to upload the file so first i am trying to get the file to some directory and then that path has to be inserted to the db,
so first i created the form

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
<button type="button" (click)="onUpload()">Upload</button>
```

After that i have the functions in my .ts files

```
onFileSelected(event){
   this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  }

onUpload(){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('productImage',  this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/uploadImage/1', fd )
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

my node rest call is as follows

```
app.post('/uploadImage/:id', upload.single("productImage")  ,(request, result) => {
    result.send(request.file);
    result.send(request.params.id);
    result.send("Done");
});
```

the part where i am confused is since i am setting the header at the node side how do i remove it from the front end to avoid the following error that says can't set headers when they are sent

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:494:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:501:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\Projects\Craiglist\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.contentType (D:\Projects\Craiglist\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:595:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\Projects\Craiglist\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:145:14)
    at app.post (D:\Projects\Craiglist\api\index.js:41:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Projects\Craiglist\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\Projects\Craiglist\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Array.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\Craiglist\api\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:53:37)
    at listener (D:\Projects\Craiglist\api\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:169:15)
```

Comment: You have three calls to `result.send()`. You can only send once. Why have you added the other calls? And what did you expect them to do?

Comment: oops my bad actually wanted to use console.log on the last two, and yeah that did solve the problem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use result.send function only once in each route.
your code should become something like this:

```
 app.post('/uploadImage/:id', upload.single("productImage")  ,(request, result) => {
    finalResult = {
    requestFile: request.file,  
    requestParams: request.params.id,
    message: "Done!"
    };
    result.send(finalResult);
});
```